# How to update controller with FXMLLoader?

Tags: java, javafx

I am able to grab the FXMLLoader controller for my controller and I am now wanting to update a method inside it. How can I do this?

```
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                    getClass().getResource(UIViewConstants.HIERARCHY_TAB_FULLNAME));
            HierarchyTabController controller = new HierarchyTabController(dataModel);
            loader.setController(controller);
            System.out.println(loader);
            loader.updateTable(dataModel) //How can I make this work?

         }
```

In my HierarchyTabController I have a method called `updateTable` so how can I call that from the instance I am getting now from loader?

If it helps, it prints out the object `java.fx.fxml.FXMLLoader@16F451AA`

Comment: Surely you mean `controller.updateTable(...)`, not `loader.updateTable(...)`??? But anyway, you haven't loaded the FXML.

Comment: @James_D That's what I mean yes, but how can I do that? I can't just call HierarchyTabController.updateTable because that won't be the specific object

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. The controller is an object associated with a UI hierarchy, which you load from an FXML file. Here you haven't loaded the FXML file (you never call `loader.load()`), so the instance of `HierarchyTabController` isn't associated with any UI. (In other words, if we assume `updateTable(..)` updates a table in the UI, the instance you created here doesn't have a table to update.)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to fix that typo, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement it:

```
Parent root;

try {
  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(                              
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResource
    (UIViewConstants.HIERARCHY_TAB_FULLNAME)); // getClassLoader() to avoid problems to find the resources when generating the jar file

  root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();

  HierarchyTabController controller =
    fxmlLoader.<HierarchyTabController>getController();
  controller.updateTable(dataModel);
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.debug(e);
}
```